# Mediapipe - installation windows

Tags: python, windows, compilation, bazel, mediapipe

When attempting to compile mediapipe **(Windows, cmd using administrator , python 3.11, VC 2019)** using bazel on my system I get
error regarding Python (copied below) I've attempted to follow the instructions at https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/724 but the error persists

`ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_execution_config_python':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:/users/nir/_bazel_nir/cpr34qgy/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 219, column 22, in _create_local_python_repository
                _check_python_bin(repository_ctx, python_bin)
        File "C:/users/nir/_bazel_nir/cpr34qgy/external/org_tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 149, column 14, in _check_python_bin
                if result.return_code == 1:
Error: 'tuple' value has no field or method 'return_code'`

Comment: check whether you have value in result before checking the  result.return_code condition.